# Ranges on seek bar

Tags: android

Hi I want to put the ranges on seek bar. I am able to run seekbar successfully. Even though on sliding i can get the values also. But on the top of it I have to set ranges as it is shown in image. Please let me know how can I do that. It would not be hardcoded because with seekbar I have given plus minus button also, so that If I click on plus button so right now range is from 0 to 100000 with 10000 interval. Then the range value will change to 100000 to 200000 and so on. so with that ranges should also change.

[image]

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please refer follwing link https://github.com/Efor18/RangeSeekBar

Comment: use setProgressDrawable with a custom Drawable that displays the ranges (class MyRangeDrawable extends Drawable)

Comment: prakash I implemented what u have refered. This is what that I have already done.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is simply indicators for the range, so it doesn't need to be part of your seekbar.

I would do it in the layout. Above the seek bar, create 10 textviews that are weighted evenly in a linearlayout.

Then just have some simple logic to update the text on these textviews when the user changes the range.